# Resolve data before route change

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

I came from Angular 1 to be honest, I know a little bit angular 2, react. I know about this both architecture but I'm not confortable to produce fast app's like a guru.

I'm having a problem. In angular it is so easy, before the routes change, I can resolve or not my data to change the route including my controller/view.

How can I do this with reacting? So change the route as soon as my data is resolved. I do not find anything interesting out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `react-router` for navigation, then you can hook the `onEnter` and defer the call to `callback` until your data is resolved.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback

Comment: But, how can I populate the data into component? Im going on this way but I dont know how to pass the response data into my component.

Comment: If you use Redux, normally you shouldn't populate the data into component directly from `onEnter`. Dispatch an action, create a reducer, update a state and then use `connect()` to pass a state to component. In your case you need to call an asynchronous method to resolve your data and you need to use either `redux thunk` or `redux saga` middleware. Usually I dispatch an action inside `componentDidMount()` method. And it is a recommended way: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: Not a perfect one, but please take a look at my side project [here](https://github.com/ming-soon/mern-starter)

Comment: You call an API to retrieve data here: https://github.com/ming-soon/mern-starter/blob/master/app/routes/User/containers/ListContainer.js#L21

Comment: Hmmm, but this example, you are fetching data inside a component after mount. I need to fetch the data before the component mount to inject into component.

Comment: In angular app, if I cant reach a route, I have an event called "$stateChangeError" and when it occurs, I send a little notification to user.

But in react, seems hard.

Comment: In the `onEnter`, you can dispatch an action and wait until it is resolved or rejected. Once resolved, call the `callback` to navigate to the specified route.

Comment: I edited my two last comment...

"I need to fetch the data before the component mount"...

Comment: hmmm... Can you have a example of an action?

Comment: But How my action communicate with my component? :'(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136503/discussion-between-joao-silva-and-ming-soon).

Comment: Answer is no longer valid since this link 404's

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways, you can try `setRouteLeaveHook`:

```
class SomeRoute extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(
            this.props.route,
            nextRoute => this.routerWillLeave(nextRoute)
        );
    }

    routerWillLeave(nextRoute: History.LocationDescriptor): boolean | void {
        /* ... *?
    }
}
```

Where `SomeRoute` is any component given as the `component` property to a `ReactRouter.Route`:

```
<Router>
    <Route component={SomeRoute}/>
</Router>
```

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ConfirmingNavigation.md

Comment: But I need to check data integrity after pass it to component. Imagine if server give me a error in response. What will happen?

I need to resolve data after component render/mount/load, whatever.